# How can I change the elements of a matrix if they satisfy some condition?

Tags: netlogo

I'm working with the matrix extension in NetLogo. I want to be able to modify specific elements of the matrix if they equal some number.

For instance if the value is 0.95 I want to run `random 2` on it so it comes out as a 1 or a 0. And if it's a 1.75 it comes out as a 1 or a 2 with `random (3 - 1) + 1`

This would change my matrix m from this:

```
  let m matrix:from-row-list [[1 0.95 0.95] [2 1 1.75] [1 2 1] ]
```

to this:

```
[[1 1 0] [.05 1 2] [.05 .25 1] ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand your updated matrix example- for example, why does the 2 in the second row become 0.05 in the output? I'm assuming you have some other rules for dealing with those numbers. Anyway, I think you can use [`matrix:map`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/matrix.html#matrix:map) to accomplish what you're after- you may just have to set up the rules in your anonymous reporter to reflect what you're after. Here is an example using the rules you supplied for values of 0.95 and 1.75:

```
extensions [ matrix ]

to matrix-manipulation
  let m matrix:from-row-list [[1 0.95 0.95] [2 1 1.75] [1 2 1] ]

  let m2 matrix:map [ i -> val-change i ] m

  print matrix:pretty-print-text m2
end

to-report val-change [ val ]
  if val = 0.95 [
    report random 2
  ]
  if val = 1.75 [
    report 1 + random 2
  ]
  report val
end
```

Output becomes:

```
[[ 1  0  1 ]
 [ 2  1  2 ]
 [ 1  2  1 ]]
```

Comment: Thank you, and you're right I had different rules for those other values. Sorry for the confusion.